# Como usar store procedure com Doctrine

Tags: php, oracle, doctrine, stored-procedures

Como uso stored procedure com Doctrine ?

Devo usar o createNativeQuery ?

Answer (score 0):

Que eu saiba só usando query nativa, assim:

```
$results = $this->getConnection()->query("SELECT NOME_DA_PROCEDURE()")
    ->fetchAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá! Obrigado por responder Marcelo!

Encontrei os meios de fazer. Existem dois métodos:

1) Usando createNativeQuery

```
    $rsm = new ResultSetMapping;
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();
    $sp = "BEGIN pk_web.sp_WEB_CONTATO(:pNOME,:pEMAIL,:pFONE,:pMENSAGEM); END;";
    $query = $em->createNativeQuery($sp,$rsm)
        ->setParameters(array(
            ':pNOME'            => $data['nome'],
            ':pEMAIL'           => $data['email'],
            ':pFONE'            => $data['fone'],
            ':pMENSAGEM'        => $data['mensagem'],
        ));
    $result = $query->getResult();
```

2) Usando PDO

```
$connection = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->getConnection()
        ->getWrappedConnection();

    $stmt = $connection->prepare("BEGIN pk_web.sp_WEB_CONTATO(:pNOME,:pEMAIL,:pFONE,:pMENSAGEM,:pMSG); END;");

    $stmt->bindParam(":pNOME",           $data['nome'],      \PDO::PARAM_STR, 255);
    $stmt->bindParam(":pEMAIL",          $data['email'],     \PDO::PARAM_STR, 255);
    $stmt->bindParam(":pFONE",           $data['fone'],      \PDO::PARAM_STR, 255);
    $stmt->bindParam(":pMENSAGEM",       $data['mensagem'],  \PDO::PARAM_STR, 8000);

    $stmt->bindParam(":pMSG",$msg,\PDO::PARAM_STR, 1000);

    $stmt->execute();

    if($msg) {
        return [
            "success" => true,
            "id" => $msg,
            "nome" => $data['nome'],
            "email" => $data['email']
        ];
    }
```

No exemplo acima, minha stored procedure esta em uma package do Oracle.
A variavel :pmsg recebe o retorno de minha stored procedure.